# max-width:-webkit-fit-content ie 8 equivalent?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Are there any hacks for `max-width:-webkit-fit-content;` for ie 8?

Trying to get a child div to not take up the whole width of the parent and this works well with ff, chrome and safari; hoping there's some hack to get it to work with ie 8 as well.

Fiddle showing the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/XtZq9/
Code for the behavior I want in ie8:

```
#wrap {
    background-color: aqua;
    width:300px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.textbox {
    background-color: yellow; 
    max-width: intrinsic;
    max-width:-webkit-fit-content;
    max-width:  -moz-max-content;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

<div id="wrap">
     <div class="textbox">
        Here is some text
    </div>  
    <div class="textbox">
        Here is other, longer, text
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Not a lot of code to go on... any reason you can't apply a conditional comment that simply sets a % width on that container for ie8?

Comment: I want the width of the container to be dynamic according to it's contents so didn't want to set any static width value; there really isn't much code to include but ill append the question to include it. here's a fiddle describing the behavior i want: http://jsfiddle.net/XtZq9/

Comment: @HelloWorld: `.textbox{float:left;} .textbox + *{clear:left;}` is a small hack that will essentially do the same: http://jsfiddle.net/XtZq9/1/ - however, I cannot test this in IE8 as I'm currently not at a Windows PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I can think of is floating your elements. Not exactly alike, but probably sufficiently alike;) You need to set extra margin though, but this should be no problem with a conditional stylesheet.

```
.textbox {
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

[Your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtZq9/3/)

Answer (score 27):

From [demosthenes.info](http://demosthenes.info/blog/975/Little-Big-Using-CSS-fit-content), I learned I can simply use

```
display: table;
```

instead of

```
width: fit-content;
```

Check the link however about problems with whitespaces. It does not apply to my case, and simply replacing *width: fit-content* with *display: table* solved my problem quite easily.

Comment: This solved it for me for an element that had `display: flex` and for which IE11 wrongly reported its height when queried with getBoundingClientRect().height. This element also had `height: fit-content` on it, which is not recognised by IE11 and doesn't really have a substitute.

Answer (score 5):

It might depends on the situation:

I had a block-level element with **width: fit-content;**. As this doesn't work on IE, the element was taking the full available width (as expected).

But I wanted it to just adjust its size to its content.

Finally, i fixed it with:

```
display: inline-flex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet; keep watching http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width &

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/6263702-css-intrinsic-sizing