# Need help understanding fit-content

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I am building a simple react webpage as a personal project.  I am using this library to give me zoom capabilities: [React-zoom-pan-pinch](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch). Before I implemented this library, my SVG element filled the screen (in red).  Which is the desired behavior.  I want it to be as big as possible.

[image: example1]

After the new code, it looks like this.

[image]

Code:

```
<TransformWrapper
      defaultScale={1}
      defaultPositionX={0}
      defaultPositionY={0}
>
  <TransformComponent>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      viewBox={"0 0 1024 792"}
    >
    ...svg stuff here
    </svg>
  </TransformComponent>
</TransformWrapper>
```

I've tried all kinds of css tricks and resizing work arounds to fix it but nothing really seemed to work.  I played around with the library's css and I found these three rules to be the culprit.  If I delete ALL 3 of these in my dev tools, then my svg returns to full size.

```
  .container { /* TransformWrapper */
    width: fit-content;
    ...
  }
  .content { /* TransformComponent */
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    ...
  }
```

I'm not amazing with CSS so I read up on these and I wouldn't think that these should be causing the behavior mentioned.  Can anyone help me understand whats going on and best ways to fix it?  I know I can manually override these values but that seems like a duct-tape approach.

## **Update**

I manually unset the `width: fit-content` and kept the `display: flex`.  I then wrapped my svg in a div with `flex-grow:1`.  However, I'd still like to know why it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: try it included: `width: auto`, `margin-right: auto`, `display: table`. it helps me.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: at first I thought that you need an alternative to fit-content, since this rule has poor browser support :)

Comment: Sergey is right, at least no IE support. Check this out, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438597/max-width-webkit-fit-content-ie-8-equivalent

Comment: It does work correctly in firefox, so I figured I'd just override the css values, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Late response but I recently ran into the same issue so for anyone curious, the `TransformComponent` component in `react-zoom-pan-pinch` constructs two divs, the wrapper and the component. You'll need to pass in styling for both if you want to override the existing styling ([source code](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/blob/e8117f61cf25c86dc6f0d40335bceedb2bf40475/src/components/transform-component/transform-component.tsx#L18)).

To get this to work for an SVG I did:

```
<TransformWrapper initialScale={1}>
      <TransformComponent
        wrapperStyle={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
        contentStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      >
          <svg>
          ...
          </svg>
      </TransformComponent>
    </TransformWrapper>
```

You can add whatever styling you want for your content and your wrapper with the above wrapper style and content style args.